# Embed Movie | want to set autoplay function dependent on whether they have visited site before

Tags: php, session, embed, autoplay, .mov

I have an embedded movie and trying to set up a php function that will let me see if user has been here before. If they have then autoplay is set to false

the followig code does not work `<?php
function autoplay(){
if ($REMOTE_ADDR == "") {
    $ip = "no ip"; 
echo "true";
}
else{ $ip = getHostByAddr($REMOTE_ADDR);
echo "false";
}
}
?>`

Any suggestions please

Answer (score 0):

you could use a cookie that will be stored in the user's browser.
session_start(); before everything else in the page, then setcookie('visited','yes',$time+2592000); after that before loading the movie check if $_COOKIE['visited'] == "yes"; and thats it. 2592000 are the seconds in a month. Paste this at the first line of your page:

```
<? session_start(); $loopif=($_COOKIE['visited']=="yes")?false:true;setcookie('visited','yes',$time+2592000); ?>
```

Then $loopif is false when the user has visited before and is true when he hasnt, so just echo it where needed.

Answer (score 0):

finished it

created two functions and reference the autoplay in the autoplay section in the embed

```
function ipfunction() {

    $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    $queryone = "SELECT * from sessions where ip='$ip'";
    $result = mysql_query($queryone);
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
        mysql_query("insert into `sessions` (`id`, `session`, `ip`) VALUES ('','','$ip')");
    } else if (mysql_num_rows($result) != 0) {
        echo "";
    }
}

function autoplay() {

    $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    $queryone = "SELECT * from sessions where ip='$ip'";
    $result = mysql_query($queryone);
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
        echo "true";
    } else if(mysql_num_rows($result) != 0) {
        echo "false";
    }
}
```